# How to read KeyVault reference c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I have add an entry in configuration in Azure to link to AzureKeyreference as display below. I am trying to get the secret call prodkey from config below.

Name: ProdContoso:ST64
Value: @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://contosokeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/prodkey/e8b00ec08bd65fc49484dd6bb445ae5c)

```
public string GetKeyData()
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

    
    var key = config["ProdContoso:ST644"];
    Console.WriteLine($"ProdContoso:ST64:{key?.Substring(0, 5) ?? "null"}");
    return key;
}
```

Comment: what is the trouble you are facing now? you can't get the secret stored in Azure key vault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Key Vault references means you're using a standardized format as the value for an application setting, that allows you to retrieve a Key Vault value by accessing the Application Setting based on its name. The Azure platform will take care of contacting Key Vault and getting the value.
They provide a way to

> work with secrets from Azure Key Vault in your App Service or Azure Functions application without requiring any code changes.

Please see [Use Key Vault references for App Service and Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli).

As far as your issues goes, please make sure you followed the steps in [Granting your app access to Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#granting-your-app-access-to-key-vault)

> 1. Create a managed identity for your application.
>    Key Vault references will use the app's system assigned identity by default,
>    but you can specify a user-assigned identity.
> 2. Create an access policy in Key Vault for the application identity you created earlier. Enable the "Get" secret permission on this policy. Do not configure the "authorized application" or applicationId settings, as this is not compatible with a managed identity.

Comment: thanks for the links which help me resolve the issue